# Can you have a run-time window instead of a MsgBox for output?

Tags: vba, ms-project

The code I currently works as follows: I type in a UID and then a message box shows the slack of a task. However, it's not possible to edit the Microsoft Project file while the message box is open.

Is there another object I can use in VBA to show the same output but allow me to work on the project file while having the output out? And, is it possible to have the output be in real time? In other words, if I make changes in my schedule, can I see the output constantly change if the slack changes as I make changes without having to run the application again?

```
Sub SlackFinder()
    Dim User_UID, User_ID As Integer
    Dim Slack As Variant
    Dim NewSlack As Variant

    User_UID = InputBox("Enter UID for slack:")
    If User_UID = "" Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo Error_Not_Found
    User_ID = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(User_UID).ID
    On Error GoTo Error_Collapsed
    Slack = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(User_UID).TotalSlack
    NewSlack = Slack / 480
    MsgBox "Total Slack: " & NewSlack
    Exit Sub

Error_Not_Found:
    MsgBox "UID " & User_UID & " not found in " & ActiveProject.Name
    Exit Sub

Error_Collapsed:
    MsgBox "UID is present but cannot be selected.  Perhaps it is collapsed?", vbOKOnly, "COLLAPSED UID?"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show real-time slack using a modeless userform. Create a userform in VBA, for example something that has a textbox for entering the task UID and a label to display the Total Slack value:

[image]

Then add this code to the UserForm module:

```
Private Sub UID_Change()
    UpdateTotalSlack
End Sub

Sub UpdateTotalSlack()
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.TSlack = "Total Slack = " & ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(Me.UID).TotalSlack / 480
End Sub
```

Add this to the Project module:

```
Sub ShowSlack()
    UserForm1.Show False
End Sub

Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)
    UserForm1.UpdateTotalSlack
End Sub
```

To start, call the `ShowSlack` procedure. This shows the user form modelessly (e.g. it floats above the MS Project window, allowing you to make changes in the schedule). Enter a Task UID in the textbox and the Total Slack will be displayed immediately and updated whenever changes are made to the schedule (thanks to the Change event code).

Comment: Thank you! This helped very much!

Comment: I got most of the code to function properly. However, when I make a change in the slack value while modifying the schedule, the slack value isn't updated. Can you explain how the project is constantly checking the project for any changes made (The Project_Change method I assume?). I have the same code but it's not updating. Thanks.

Comment: To add more detail, I know my program isn't entering the Project_Change method when I make an update on the Project file, should I be changing the "pj" to something else?

Comment: Check out [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355232(v=office.12).aspx) for details on how to implement events in MS Project.

Comment: You don't need to change anything about the code above (except if your user form has a different name). My guess is that your code is not in the project module (e.g. ThisProject); just move it there (see link in previous comment for more info).

Comment: Ok, I got the popup "hi" to work (so that's good!) but the project doesn't recognize Userform10. I'll show you my code as an update: In the order of Project module, module29, and userform. See my answer below for updated code.

Comment: Got it to finally work! I had macros disabled and turned it on. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Project Module:

```
Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)
MsgBox "hi"
UserForm10.UpdateTotalSlack
End Sub
```

Module 29:

```
Sub ShowSlack()
    UserForm10.Show False
End Sub
```

Userform10:

```
Dim User_UID As Variant
Dim TSlack As Variant


Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    User_UID = UserForm10.TextBox3.Value
    UpdateTotalSlack
End Sub

Sub UpdateTotalSlack()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not User_UID = "" Then
        TSlack = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(User_UID).TotalSlack / 480
    Else
        TSlack = ""
    End If
    UserForm10.Label1.Caption = TSlack
End Sub
```